# Error trying to render an array of objects from the database

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I'm trying to load an Array of Questions for a Quiz App, but in the method which collects the questions from the JSON database, the following warning error occurs:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {number, answer, isCorrect}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```js
getRandomizedQuestions = () => {
    const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/questions'
    fetch(apiUrl)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
            console.log("From database:");
            console.log(result);

            let amountOfQuestions = result.length;
            let randomizedResult = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < amountOfQuestions; i++) {
                let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * result.length);
                randomizedResult.push(result[randomIndex]);
                result.splice(randomIndex, 1);
            }
            this.setState({questions: randomizedResult });

            }, (error) => {
                console.log('An unexpected error occurred', error);
            });
};
```

Comment: can you add `render()` as well?

Comment: cant add the whole render(too long) but i use it here:

` render() {
  return (
   <div className='quiz-window'>
    {this.state.questions.map((question, index) => (
     <div key={index}>
      {question.title}
     </div>)
    )}`

`       <div className='answer-section'>
        {
         this.state.questions.map((answerOption, index) => (
          <button key={index} onClick={() => this.handleAnswerOptionClick(answerOption.isCorrect)}>{answerOption.answers}</button>
         ))}
       </div>`

Comment: can you share your question JSON data? I think I get it now, there is a problem with the second map you should map into the answer, not into question, share your JSON data ill make you an example.

Comment: again too long so i split it into 2:

{
  "questions": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "Pi Dezimal",
      "author": "Timo",
      "isMC": false,
      "question": "Wie lauten die 4 ersten Dezimalstellen von Pi?",
      "answers": "1415",
      "category": null
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Längster Fluss",
      "author": "Timo",
      "isMC": true,
      "question": "Welcher ist der längte Fluss der Welt?",
      "answers": [

Comment: {
          "number": 1,
          "answer": "Donau",
          "isCorrect": false
        },
        {
          "number": 2,
          "answer": "Nil",
          "isCorrect": true
        },
        {
          "number": 3,
          "answer": "Wolga",
          "isCorrect": false
        },
        {
          "number": 4,
          "answer": "Amazonas",
          "isCorrect": false
        }
      ],
      "category": null
    },

Comment: {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Energieaufnahme Pflanzen",
      "author": "Timo",
      "isMC": false,
      "question": "Durch welchen Vorgang gewinnen Pflanzen Energie?",
      "answers": "Photosynthese",
      "category": null
    }
  ],

Comment: yes, check my answer now, btw u should add this detail to your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning an object of answer `{number, answer, isCorrect}` you should just map into answer after mapping into question:

```
render() {
  // add logic and constant here
  return (
    //... add another component or jsx
    <div className='show-score'>{showScore}</div>
    <div className='quiz-window'>
      {this.state.questions.map((question, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          {question.title}
          <div className='answer-section'>
            {question.answers.map(answer => (
              <button key={answer.number} onClick={() => this.handleAnswerOptionClick(answer.isCorrect)}>
                {answer.answer}
              </button>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
    //... add another component or jsx
  )
}
```

**Bonus**: For randomizing items inside array Instead of:

```
let randomizedResult = [];
for (let i = 0; i < amountOfQuestions; i++) {
   let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * result.length);
   randomizedResult.push(result[randomIndex]);
   result.splice(randomIndex, 1);
}
```

Use this code:

```
const randomizedResult  = result.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i still get the same error with that code unfortunately

Comment: but where do i add the showscore? function? can you give me the complete render?

Comment: ok ill make a render function based on what you commented.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/c98oe i made a codesandbox if that helps